# LibreOffice 4.1 Start Center does not show in Lubuntu

Tags: installation, lubuntu, libreoffice, menu

I have recently upgraded libreOffice to 4.1. However, after the first attempt at installing it manually, it appears that I do not have as many options as I did in the previous version. I uninstalled then re installed LibreOffice again to only have a limited amount of options available.

Is there any way to get the **LibreOffice Start Center** to show in the start menu>office> drop down list? I have also checked LibreOffice's website and see that Math is available to open separately. But the only way to open it is through an already open LO program.

I'm running Lubuntu 13.10 on a Toshiba Satellite A135-S4427.

[UPDATE]
Tried to add a screenshot of the office menu but I have to have 10 rep points to do so :(

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to get the Start Center and Math/Formulas app to show in the office menu shortcuts by using the Menu Editor under the *start menu* > *system tools* > *Menu Editor*. From there, I have been able to add/make not hidden these missing shortcuts from the office start menu.

For anyone that is having this issue, please check your Menu Editor or install one to be able to do so.

The Menu Editor that I have on Lubuntu is: MenuLibre v13.01.4 [launchpad.net/menulibre](http://launchpad.net/menulibre)